# Creating a stored procedure for the first time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to produce a Trial Balance report in Microsoft SSRS for the very first time (Yes, its scares me too!) and am having some difficulty.   Previously, I've either used Business Objects or MS Access to facilitate reporting requirements from the source database.

The SQL query within the below CREATE SP statement runs correctly but I get problems when trying to convert it into a new stored procedure:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:  <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GDM_TrialBalanceEL3_DEV_CVB]

 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@grpcode varchar(12),
@company varchar(12),
@currency varchar(12),
@begperiod int,
@startperiod int,
@endperiod int

AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;


--- DECLARE VARIABLES ----

DECLARE @NominalLevel int,
        @Currency varchar(3),
        @cmpcode varchar (12),
        @FromYear int,
        @FromPeriod int,
        @FromPeriodMMMM int,
        @ToYear int,
        @ToPeriod int,
        @ToPeriodMMMM int,
        @BookingType varchar (2)

--- SET PARAMETERS  (enter values) ---        

SET @NominalLevel = 3
SET @Currency = 'EUR'
SET @cmpcode = 'BEC001'
SET @FromYear = 2013
SET @FromPeriod = 1
SET @ToYear = 2013
SET @ToPeriod = 12
SET @BookingType = 'STCO'

--- COMBINE PARAMETERS ----

SET @FromPeriodMMMM = @FromYear * 10000 + @FromPeriod
SET @ToPeriodMMMM = @ToYear * 10000 + @ToPeriod

------OPENING BALANCE ----

SELECT a.cmpcode
   ,g.grpcode
   , SUBSTRING(a.el1,1,2) AS 'ST/CO'
   , a.el2
   , a.el3
   , CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN a.el2 ELSE a.el3 END AS 'Account'
   , el.sname AS AccountName
   ,'Opening Balance' AS Movement
   , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' THEN SUM(a.valuehome) ELSE SUM(a.valuedual) END AS 'Amount'
   , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' AND a.deb_cred_ind=160 THEN SUM(a.valuehome)WHEN @Currency<>'EUR' AND a.deb_cred_ind=160 THEN SUM(a.valuedual)ELSE 0 END AS 'Credit'
   , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' AND a.deb_cred_ind=161 THEN SUM(a.valuehome)WHEN @Currency<>'EUR' AND a.deb_cred_ind=161 THEN SUM(a.valuedual)ELSE 0 END AS 'Debit'   
   , c.l1hdrtxt
   , c.l2hdrtxt
   , c.l3hdrtxt
   , c.leafhdrtxt

FROM        CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_agmlist b,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_docline a,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_himlist c,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_dochead d,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_perlist e,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_company f,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_grplist g,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_element el

WHERE 
((a.el3 BETWEEN b.el3incfrom AND b.el3incto) 
AND((b.el3excfrom is NULL) OR (a.el3 NOT BETWEEN b.el3excfrom AND b.el3excto)))
AND c.code='TRIALBALANCE'
AND c.grpcode=b.code 
AND a.cmpcode = d.cmpcode
AND a.doccode = d.doccode
AND a.docnum = d.docnum 
AND d.yr = e.yr 
AND d.period = e.period
AND d.cmpcode = e.cmpcode 
AND d.cmpcode = f.code
AND a.el1 = g.code 
AND a.cmpcode= g.cmpcode
AND g.elmlevel = 1
AND d.cmpcode = el.cmpcode 
AND el.code = CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN a.el2 ELSE a.el3 END
AND el.elmlevel= @NominalLevel
AND a.cmpcode = @cmpcode
AND d.yr*10000+d.Period BETWEEN f.yrmin*10000  AND (@FromPeriodMMMM-1)
AND        g.grpcode = @BookingType
AND a.el3 < '60000000'        

GROUP BY        a.cmpcode
,g.grpcode
, SUBSTRING(a.el1,1,2) 
, a.el2
, a.el3
, CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN a.el2 ELSE a.el3 END
, EL.sname
, a.deb_cred_ind
, c.l1hdrtxt
, c.l2hdrtxt
, c.l3hdrtxt
, c.leafhdrtxt

UNION ALL

----MOVEMENT ----

SELECT a.cmpcode
       ,g.grpcode
   , SUBSTRING(a.el1,1,2) AS 'ST/CO'
   , a.el2
   , a.el3
   , CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN a.el2 ELSE a.el3 END AS Account
   , el.sname as AccountName
   ,'Movement' AS Movement
   , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' THEN SUM(a.valuehome) ELSE SUM(a.valuedual) END AS 'Amount'
   , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' AND a.deb_cred_ind=160 THEN SUM(a.valuehome)WHEN @Currency<>'EUR' AND a.deb_cred_ind=160 THEN SUM(a.valuedual)ELSE 0 END AS 'Credit'
   , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' AND a.deb_cred_ind=161 THEN SUM(a.valuehome)WHEN @Currency<>'EUR' AND a.deb_cred_ind=161 THEN SUM(a.valuedual)ELSE 0 END AS 'Debit'
   , c.l1hdrtxt
   , c.l2hdrtxt
   , c.l3hdrtxt
   , c.leafhdrtxt

FROM        CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_agmlist b,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_docline a,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.Oas_himlist c,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_dochead d,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_perlist e,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_company f,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_grplist g,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_element el

WHERE 
((a.el3 BETWEEN b.el3incfrom AND b.el3incto) 
AND((b.el3excfrom is NULL) OR (a.el3 NOT BETWEEN b.el3excfrom AND B.el3excto)))
AND c.code='TRIALBALANCE'
AND c.grpcode=b.code 
AND a.cmpcode = d.cmpcode
AND a.doccode = d.doccode
AND a.docnum = d.docnum 
AND d.yr = e.yr 
AND d.period = e.period
AND d.cmpcode = e.cmpcode 
AND d.cmpcode = f.code
AND a.el1 = g.code 
AND a.cmpcode= g.cmpcode
AND g.elmlevel = 1
AND d.cmpcode = el.cmpcode 
AND el.code = Case When @NominalLevel=2 Then a.el2 else a.el3 end
AND el.elmlevel= @NominalLevel
AND a.cmpcode = @cmpcode
AND d.yr*10000+d.Period between @FromPeriodMMMM and @ToPeriodMMMM
AND        g.grpcode = @BookingType

GROUP BY        a.cmpcode
            ,g.grpcode
, SUBSTRING(a.el1,1,2) 
, a.el2
, a.el3
, CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN a.el2 ELSE a.el3 END
, EL.sname
, a.deb_cred_ind
, c.l1hdrtxt
, c.l2hdrtxt
, c.l3hdrtxt
, c.leafhdrtxt

UNION ALL

---- RETAINED EARNINGS ---        

SELECT        a.cmpcode
,g.grpcode
,SUBSTRING(a.el1,1,2) as 'ST/CO'
,(SELECT el1.subselm from oas_element AS el1 WHERE el1.elmlevel=3 AND el1.cmpcode = @cmpcode AND el1.code='53100000')
,'53100000'
, CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN (SELECT el1.subselm from oas_element AS el1 WHERE el1.elmlevel=3 AND el1.cmpcode = @cmpcode AND el1.code='53100000')  ELSE '53100000' END AS Account
, CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN (SELECT el2.sname FROM oas_element AS el1 ,oas_element AS el2 WHERE el1.elmlevel=3 AND el2.elmlevel=2 AND el1.cmpcode = @cmpcode AND el1.code='53100000' AND el2.code=el1.subselm AND el2.cmpcode = el1.cmpcode)
  ELSE (SELECT el1.sname from oas_element AS el1 WHERE el1.elmlevel=3 AND el1.cmpcode = @cmpcode AND el1.code='53100000')END AS 'AccountName'
, 'Opening Balance'
    , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' THEN SUM(a.valuehome) ELSE SUM(a.valuedual) END AS 'Amount'
    , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' AND SUM(a.valuehome)<0  THEN SUM(a.valuehome) WHEN @Currency<>'EUR' AND SUM(a.valuedual)<0  THEN SUM(a.valuedual)ELSE 0 END AS 'Credit'
    , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' AND SUM(a.valuehome)>0  THEN SUM(a.valuehome) WHEN @Currency<>'EUR' AND SUM(a.valuedual)<0  THEN SUM(a.valuedual)ELSE 0 END AS 'Debit'
, 'BALANCE SHEET'        
, 'EQUITY'
, 'TOTAL RETAINED EARNINGS'
, 'RETAINED EARNINGS'

FROM CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_agmlist b,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_docline a,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.Oas_himlist c,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_dochead d,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_perlist e,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_company f,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_grplist g,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_element el

WHERE 
((a.el3 BETWEEN b.el3incfrom AND b.el3incto) 
AND((b.el3excfrom is NULL) OR (a.el3 NOT BETWEEN b.el3excfrom AND B.el3excto)))
AND c.code='TRIALBALANCE'
AND c.grpcode=b.code 
AND a.cmpcode = d.cmpcode
AND a.doccode = d.doccode
AND a.docnum = d.docnum 
AND d.yr = e.yr 
AND d.period = e.period
AND d.cmpcode = e.cmpcode 
AND d.cmpcode = f.code
AND a.el1 = g.code 
AND a.cmpcode= g.cmpcode 
AND g.elmlevel = 1
AND d.cmpcode = el.cmpcode 
AND el.code = CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN a.el2 ELSE a.el3 END
AND el.elmlevel= @NominalLevel
AND a.cmpcode = @cmpcode
AND d.yr*10000+d.Period between f.yrmin*10000 and (@FromPeriodMMMM-1)
AND        g.grpcode = @BookingType
AND a.el3 > '60000000'

GROUP BY        a.cmpcode,g.grpcode,substring(a.el1,1,2)


UNION ALL


---- CY PROFIT/LOSS ---        


SELECT        a.cmpcode
, g.grpcode
, substring(a.el1,1,2) as 'ST/CO'
, (SELECT el1.subselm from oas_element AS el1 WHERE el1.elmlevel=3 AND el1.cmpcode = @cmpcode AND el1.code='53100001')
, '53100001'
, CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN(SELECT el1.subselm from oas_element AS el1 WHERE el1.elmlevel=3 AND el1.cmpcode = @cmpcode AND el1.code='53100001') 
  ELSE '53100001' 
  END AS Account
, CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN (SELECT el2.sname FROM oas_element AS el1 ,oas_element AS el2 WHERE el1.elmlevel=3 AND el2.elmlevel=2 AND el1.cmpcode = @cmpcode AND el1.code='53100001' AND el2.code=el1.subselm AND el2.cmpcode = el1.cmpcode)
  ELSE (SELECT el1.sname from oas_element AS el1 WHERE el1.elmlevel=3 AND el1.cmpcode = @cmpcode AND el1.code='53100001')END AS 'AccountName'
, 'Movement'
    , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' THEN SUM(a.valuehome) ELSE SUM(a.valuedual) END AS 'Amount'
, CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' AND SUM(a.valuehome)<0  THEN SUM(a.valuehome) WHEN @Currency<>'EUR' AND SUM(a.valuedual)<0  THEN SUM(a.valuedual)ELSE 0 END AS 'Credit'
        , CASE WHEN @Currency='EUR' AND SUM(a.valuehome)>0  THEN SUM(a.valuehome) WHEN @Currency<>'EUR' AND SUM(a.valuedual)<0  THEN SUM(a.valuedual)ELSE 0 END AS 'Debit'
, 'BALANCE SHEET'
, 'EQUITY'
, 'TOTAL RETAINED EARNINGS'
, 'RETAINED EARNINGS'

FROM CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_agmlist b,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_docline a,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.Oas_himlist c,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_dochead d,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_perlist e,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_company f,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_grplist g,
CODATEST_EU1.dbo.oas_element el

WHERE 
((a.el3 BETWEEN b.el3incfrom AND b.el3incto) 
AND((b.el3excfrom is NULL) OR (a.el3 NOT BETWEEN b.el3excfrom AND B.el3excto)))
AND c.code='TRIALBALANCE'
AND c.grpcode=b.code 
AND a.cmpcode = d.cmpcode
AND a.doccode = d.doccode
AND a.docnum = d.docnum 
AND d.yr = e.yr 
AND d.period = e.period
AND d.cmpcode = e.cmpcode 
AND d.cmpcode = f.code
AND a.el1 = g.code 
AND a.cmpcode= g.cmpcode
AND g.elmlevel = 1
AND d.cmpcode = el.cmpcode 
AND a.el3 >= '60000000'
AND el.code = CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN a.el2 ELSE a.el3 END
AND el.elmlevel= @NominalLevel
AND a.cmpcode = @cmpcode
AND d.yr*10000+d.Period between @FromPeriodMMMM and @ToPeriodMMMM
AND        g.grpcode = @BookingType

GROUP BY a.cmpcode ,g.grpcode , substring(a.el1,1,2)
```

When trying to run the SQL to create the stored procedure,  I'm getting the message :

Msg 134, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GDM_TrialBalanceEL3_DEV_CVB, Line 26
The variable name '@Currency' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GDM_TrialBalanceEL3_DEV_CVB, Line 40
Must declare the scalar variable "@cmpcode".

N.B. There are around 10 additional examples of the Msg 137 for differing variables but I imagine that if I understand the logic for 1 I should be able to resolve the other 9?

From my google  research so far this could be due to a variety of issues (scalar variable = Go statement forcing a re declare of variable etc) but on checking there are no GO statements, only UNION and JOIN conditions so I'm not sure where it fits into what might be the probable cause.

I'd be very grateful if someone could help (and explain why so as I don't make the same mistake again) as I urgently need to create this SP today and it seems that the DBA resource is down with the flu..

Comment: are you missing end bracket?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `@Currency` as two times..Remove one

add one more bracket in the end

Comment: Hi,  I commented out the details under the section "Add the parameters for the stored procedure here" and it now runs through until line 294 where it's flagging an incorrect syntax near ')'.  Would you mind throwing an eye over it?  (Think this is a case of casn't see the wood for the trees!)

Answer (score 0):

change your last `WHERE` to

```
WHERE 
((a.el3 BETWEEN b.el3incfrom AND b.el3incto) 
AND((b.el3excfrom is NULL) OR (a.el3 NOT BETWEEN b.el3excfrom AND B.el3excto)) -- one to many here (removed)
AND c.code='TRIALBALANCE'
AND c.grpcode=b.code 
AND a.cmpcode = d.cmpcode
AND a.doccode = d.doccode
AND a.docnum = d.docnum 
AND d.yr = e.yr 
AND d.period = e.period
AND d.cmpcode = e.cmpcode 
AND d.cmpcode = f.code
AND a.el1 = g.code 
AND a.cmpcode= g.cmpcode
AND g.elmlevel = 1
AND d.cmpcode = el.cmpcode 
AND a.el3 >= '60000000'
AND el.code = CASE WHEN @NominalLevel=2 THEN a.el2 ELSE a.el3 END
AND el.elmlevel= @NominalLevel
AND a.cmpcode = @cmpcode
AND d.yr*10000+d.Period between @FromPeriodMMMM and @ToPeriodMMMM
AND        g.grpcode = @BookingType) -- closing bracket here added
GROUP BY a.cmpcode ,g.grpcode , substring(a.el1,1,2)
```

Comment: Tried that and still doesn't like it - same message, with or without the closing bracket.

Comment: I am getting rather embarassed by this now but I sincerely appreciate your patience! I copy pasted your suggested amendments as instructed (after removing the commented out bits) but I'm afraid its still giving the same message (refers to line 291)

Comment: Problem resolved. After adding in the brackets as described above, I added in "end" and query completed correctly.  many thanks to those who helped #unsungheroes